# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, server, request, postman

I'm trying to send a post using Postman Application, my Js code is actualy the one that I'll post down here and it represents the POST.
My request from body is :

```
{

    "username" : "UserAbc",
    "password" : "password"
}
```

The error is the one that I wrote in title. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
      const username = req.body.username;
      const password = req.body.password;

      if (!username || !password) {
        res.json({
          error: 'Missing required parameters'
        });
        return;
      }

      let user = new User({
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
        user.save();

      let tokenKey = uuidv1();
      let newToken = new Token({
        token: tokenKey,
        expire: ~~(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600 * 24,
      })
      newToken.save();

      res.status(200).send({ token: tokenKey });
    });
```

Comment: In the post method, above `const username...` add `console.log(req);` and then open the broswer console and refresh the page.  Have a look what `req` actually is, because I suspect it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your POST data is not being parsed on the server.

There could be a couple reasons for that.

1. Make sure you have a body parser such as [expressjs/body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

   After you run `npm install body-parser` then in your code, you need to add this *before* any routes that use `req.body`:

   ```js
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

   app.use(bodyParser.json())
   ```
2. If you already have a body-parser then in Postman the body mime-type is not being set to `application/json`, make sure you set the type to JSON:
   [image: Setting body type to JSON]

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error, it seems that you're not using a body-parsing middleware, You'll have to do something like:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

in order for the `body` property to be set on the request object.

[More details](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in:
`const username = req.body.username;`

`req` does not contain a `body`.

Try this line of code to see if your error goes away.
`const username = (req.body || {}).username;`

This is not a solution but a way to see if this is the problem.  If your error becomes something else you've found the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Now i receive: { "error": "Missing required parameters" }. I think that my Json Format is the problem now.